# Why do we need 2 different grounds for connecting 2 thyristors back to back?

Tags: power-electronics, ground, thyristor

[image]

As seen above, these thyristors are connected back to back to resemble a TRIAC, but for high power applications.

People say because they get shorted, but how exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: G is for "gate," not "ground."

Comment: There is no ground shown in your schematic.

Comment: To trigger T1 you need a current to flow from G1 to K1 on the other hand to trigger T2 you need a current to flow from G2 to K2.

Comment: Two thyristors connected in (anti)parallel like you show with the gates also connected to each other is called a **TRIAC**. These are used for AC voltages and currents. When the current flows in one direction, one thyristor can be used, when the current flows in the other direction the other thyristor is used. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC There isn't much point in keeping the gates separate unless you have a special reason (I do not know good reason for it).

Comment: so each thyristor need its own triggering circuitry, the problem it is written each triggering circuit must not have the same ground!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - SCRs are available in higher current ratings than Triacs, so anti-parallel SCRs are still useful.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie TRIACS also have assymetrical behaviour since the device is not symmetrical. Antiparallel triacs are symmetrical. A TRIAC is similar to, but not the same as antiparallel thyristors.

Comment: @zezoooo6789 Terminology wise, those are anti-parallel. Back-to-back would mean they are in series but facing opposite directions, similar to if you stood back-to-back with someone else

Answer (score 2):

An SCR Gate input is always *referenced* to the Cathode (K). So you need two references, not two grounds. A general purpose gate drive circuit shouldn't depend on either Cathode being grounded, so both SCR gate drives should be isolated. Isolation can use transformers and/or opto-isolators.

These references could be considered to be isolated grounds, but for a relatively simple circuit like a gate drive, it is best not to refer to the references as grounds.